# How do I batch resize all images to sqares with Image Magick?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

OK. I have a horizontal image, let's say 2000 x 300. I want to overwrite that image and create a new one that is 2000 x 2000 with the old image center in the middle and vertically, with white space around it. I also want to do this in batch with many different images of different sizes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-resize`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#resize) to resize the image to 2000x2000, [`-background`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#background) to set the background to white, [`-gravity`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#gravity) to center the original image on the canvas, and [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent) to resize the canvas itself (to cause the image to sit in the centre if it wasn't square originally).

```
convert [imagename] -resize 2000x2000 -background white \
                    -gravity center -extent 2000x2000 [imagename]
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I was told something else but it didn't seem right. This makes sense. Thank you.