# how to resize width on 500 pictures with adobe photophop at one time?

Tags: resize, photoshop, image

how to resize width on 500 pictures with adobe photophop at one time?
Lets say if all 500 pictures have 1080 width how you can do 500 width on all of the pictures instead each of them?

Comment: If you have access to a linux box, you can use image magick. See [this related question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793777/how-do-i-batch-resize-all-images-to-sqares-with-image-magick

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I don't know about Adobe, and I do not think this questions belongs to Stackoverflow.

But it is easy to be done with IrfanView free program. Install program, open it, press `b`, add your photos and select bulk resize option

Comment: oh sorry I see lots of people posting how to questions about coding emails so I jumped in. But i m not referring to rezise the data of the image. just the width. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you mean whe you say `not referring to rezise the data of the image. just the width` -- I refered you to regular program that resizes your pictures in bulk.

Comment: http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-batch-resize-in-photoshop got it